# jquery vote up down, request for some help

Tags: javascript, jquery, voting

I want to make some changes in the following piece of code.

The above example shows calculated number of votes (vote ups - votes down). And when you click on any thumbe, it disappears the thumbs and shows the updated votes. I want to make changes that in begining it shows vote up and vote down separately (which are stored in database separately). and after thumb up or down is pressed, it should not remove the thumbs, but it should show the updated vote up and down separatetly. As shown in the image below.
[image]

Here are pieces of code:

Main page having html/CSS and jquery code.
http://pastebin.com/RC6dj6N5

vote processng code:
http://pastebin.com/heszKyDc

PS. I have tried to change by myself but I could not do. Any help will be much appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your page tries to load fireintheyear.com/in.cgi?15 which is blocked by Google Safe Browsing. Please remove the link from your question to not put users at risks.

Comment: Actually that was demo which I found by google (not my page), surprisingly I did not get any warning, neither it redirected me anywhere, anyway I have removed the link. Hope someone can still help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, with your php code you query the database to find out what the upvote is and what the down vote is. Output each to their respective thumb.

From here there is two ways(I would do the latter)
1: User clicks on a thumb and it posts back to the server and increments by 1(but there should be a rule to not become negative).

2: Use jQuery and ajax. Once the user clicks a thumb you use ajax to query the database and update the vote without a full page load. The ajax callback could update the vote at the page level.
Or
When the user clicks the thumb it auto increments the inner value by 1 and then updates the database behind the scenes, you could stop there or do #2 on the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show where you've gotten stuck?

It looks like you need to return `curvotes[0]` or `curvotes[1]` based on whether it's a vote up or down request instead of `getEffectiveVotes`.

Also, instead of just the `votes_count` div in the html, create one for up and one for down that get updated in the ajax success.

Comment: Thanks. In original code, the thumbs div disappears after voting, but i want to show it after voting too, i tried removing some code of jquery from main page, but it stuck there.

Comment: yes, i tried to change getEffectiveVotes function, as gets both values(up and down) from db, and calculates and return the calculated value. I tried returning both values separately but seems it does not work.

Comment: "It does not work" is a hard issue to solve. You should pastebin your changes. To stop the thumbs from disappearing, remove the `$('#vote_buttons`).remove()` calls.

Comment: I tried already removing "$('#vote_buttons).remove()", but it results showing the spinner endlessly, and the buttons do not appear.

Comment: Ahh, just noticed. The call to `$(this).parent().html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'/>");` changes the content of the vote_buttons to be a spinner. if you remove that call, your thumbs won't disappear.